# Is it possible to rollback function action in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Suppose i wan't to insert Data into 2 different tables, in codeigniter,

for example :

- Insert into **UserProfile** table: name , mail to 
  (get an id and use it in the next table)
- Insert **Employees** table : UserProfile_id, shifts , position.

Up to now, all is working good, what can i do if i want to commit the action only if  both insertions are commited...how can i rollback in case the first insertion went well and i don't want an empty profile....
My problem is that once the first insertion is committed ,suppose something went wrong in the next insertion - i get data to one table... any ideas?

Comment: you should remove the `c` tag as its not related to your question.

Comment: see the updated answer @user3387719

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Transactions](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html) in codeigniter.

Syntax(Given in Document as well):

```
$this->db->trans_begin();

$this->db->query('AN SQL QUERY...');
$this->db->query('ANOTHER QUERY...');
$this->db->query('AND YET ANOTHER QUERY...');

if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
{
        $this->db->trans_rollback();
}
else
{
        $this->db->trans_commit();
}
```

> Make sure to use $this->db->trans_begin() when running manual
>   transactions, NOT $this->db->trans_start().

Also see  [strict-mode](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html#strict-mode).

**UPDATED**

For multiple models you can us this approach(my opinion), Not sure if its the only/best one:

```
// MODEL_x

public function functionX($data)
{
    return  $this->db->insert('table_x',$data);
}
// MODEL_y

public function functionY($data)
{
    return  $this->db->insert('table_y',$data);
}

//controller
$this->db->trans_start();
$this->model_x->functionX();
$this->model_y->functionY();
$this->db->trans_complete();
if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE) {
  //log error  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use codeigniter's Transactions to accomplish your task as it will only insert or commit your data if both or all of your queries are successfully executed.

To run your queries using transactions you will use the $this->db->trans_start() and $this->db->trans_complete() functions as follows:

```
$this->db->trans_start();
   $this->db->query('AN SQL QUERY...');
   $this->db->query('ANOTHER QUERY...');
   $this->db->query('AND YET ANOTHER QUERY...');
$this->db->trans_complete();
```

So, you just need to cover your queries between `$this->db->trans_start();` and `$this->db->trans_complete();`

Ref :https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html

Comment: Thanks, but, what if i'm working with 2 different  Models, each contains a query of it's own , for example : EmployeeProfile ( inserts profile), EmployeeDetails ( inserts user details) , both are being called from Employee controller in a method the takes arguments and pass them to the model....

Comment: If hope you are calling those models one after other,then try calling them between transactions & let me know

Comment: If it helped you should mark it as answer to help others

Comment: You will be seeing a check mark below the up vote down vote section for specific answer,you can click on that check to mark it as answer